# webapp2: username not defined at get request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am learning web-programming using webapp2 on google app engine, and following a tutorial on udacity(archived, therefore student community not active there.) Can someone please tell me why I am getting username not defined in my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tekforce/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/tekforce/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/tekforce/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/tekforce/Desktop/helloUdacity/hello-udacity.py", line 40, in <module>
    class LoginPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  File "/home/tekforce/Desktop/helloUdacity/hello-udacity.py", line 66, in LoginPage
    if not valid_username(username):
NameError: name 'username' is not defined
INFO     2014-02-03 22:07:26,452 module.py:612] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Below is my python code, I am trying to execute.

```
import webapp2
import cgi
import re


def escape_html(s):
    return cgi.escape(s, quote=True)

form = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Unit 2 Rot 13</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2>Enter some text to ROT13:</h2>
        <form method="post">
        <textarea name="text" style="height: 100px; width: 400px; ">
        %(text)s
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
       """

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write_form(self, text = ''):
        self.response.out.write(form % {'text': escape_html(text)})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        content = self.request.get('text').encode('rot13')
        self.write_form(content)

class LoginPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
    PASSWORD_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
    EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")

    @classmethod
    def valid_username(self,username):
        return username and LoginPage.USER_RE.match(username)

    @classmethod
    def valid_password(self,password):
        return password and LoginPage.PASSWORD_RE.match(password)

    @classmethod
    def valid_email(self, email):
        return not email or LoginPage.EMAIL_RE.match(email)

    def get(self):
        self.render("signup.html")

    def post(self):
        hasError = False
        username = self.request.get('username')
        password = self.request.get('password')
        verify = self.request.get('verify')
        email = self.request.get('email')

        # These params are send back to rendering,
        params = dict(username = username, email = email)

    if not valid_username(username):
        params['error_username'] = "Thats not a valid user name."
        hasError = True

    if not valid_password(password):
        params['error_username'] = "Thats not a valid password."
        hasError = True

    elif valid_password(password) != verify:
        params['error_verify'] = "Password do not match."
        hasError = True

    if not valid_email(email):
        params['error_email'] = "Thats not a valid email"
        hasError = True

    if hasError:
        self.render("signup.html",**params)
    else:
        self.redirect('/welcome?username='+username)

class Welcome(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
    if LoginForm.valid_username(username):
        self.render('welcome.html',username = username)
    else:
        self.redirect('/sign')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ('/sign', LoginPage),
                              ('/welcome',welcome)],
                              debug=True)
```

Below is my signup.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sign Up</title>
<style type="text/css">
.label {text-align: right}
.error {color: red}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Signup</h2>
<form method="post">
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td class="label">
Username
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{username}}">
</td>
<td class="error">
{{error_username}}
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">
Password
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="password" value="">
</td>
<td class="error">
{{error_password}}
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">
Verify Password
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="verify" value="">
</td>
<td class="error">
{{error_verify}}
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">
Email (optional)
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email" value="{{email}}">
</td>
<td class="error">
{{error_email}}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is misindented (from the following line on)

```
if not valid_username(username):
```

Indent your code one more level (so that it belong to the `post` function) and you should get rid of the problem.